# Json URL with multiple dictionaries trying to extract keys ,values to dataframe

Tags: python, json, dataframe

I am trying to extract the details from the following URL

```
https://api.covid19india.org/districts_daily.json
```

I have used the following code to extract the keys and values .

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import urllib.request, json 
import pandas as pd
from flatten_json import flatten
#from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
with urllib.request.urlopen("https://api.covid19india.org/districts_daily.json") as url:
      d = json.load(url) 
d
```

I have tried extracting the details about each state and its district covid19 info. tried using a lot of methods by going through StackOverflow and other forums. finally succeeded by providing  values manually  for state and district to extract the COVID 19 info as below
[image]

I tried iterating the same ended up in unhashable type list error. used the following code for the same

```
l = ['Tamil Nadu','West Bengal']
df =[]
for i in range(0,len(l)):
    df.append(json_normalize( d,['districtsDaily',l,l[i]]))
```

I am looking for pointers that will extract all data from JSON to a data frame.

output in the below format would help.
[image]

Thanks

Comment: What's the output format that you would like to have? It would help if you showed a sample output table of your desired result.

Comment: @KurtKline Thanks for your response. Updated the question with the format. or any format of your choice whichever works for you. I just need them in the data frame. Thanks for your help again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative, with the extractions within Python ... final output for viz purposes will be Pandas. usually, for such work, dictionaries can prove to be faster than loading into Pandas, especially for non-numerical computations.

The main part is to attach the state and districts to the innermost dictionary :

```
#read in data
import requests
data = requests.get(url).json()

#initialize empty list
d = []
#a couple of nested for loops :
#get the states and districts in the districtsDaily key
for state, state_vals in data.get("districtsDaily").items():
    #get the districts and results 
    for district, dist_vals in state_vals.items():
        #for every result, attach the district and state keys
        for entries in dist_vals:
            entries.update({"district":district, "state":state})
            #load into a list
            d.append(entries)

#read into a dataframe
res = pd.DataFrame(d)

res.head()

    active  confirmed   deceased    recovered   date    district    state   notes
0   0   1   0   1   2020-04-21  North and Middle Andaman    Andaman and Nicobar Islands NaN
1   0   1   0   1   2020-04-22  North and Middle Andaman    Andaman and Nicobar Islands 
2   0   1   0   1   2020-04-23  North and Middle Andaman    Andaman and Nicobar Islands 
3   0   1   0   1   2020-04-24  North and Middle Andaman    Andaman and Nicobar Islands 
4   0   1   0   1   2020-04-25  North and Middle Andaman    Andaman and Nicobar Islands
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**Full Code Block**

```
d = json.loads(data)

state_data = d['districtsDaily']

df = pd.DataFrame()
for state, districts in state_data.items(): 
    for district, values in districts.items(): 
        df_district = json_normalize(state_data, [state, district])
        df_district.insert(0, 'state', state)
        df_district.insert(1, 'district', district)
    df = pd.concat([df, df_district])

print(df[['date', 'state', 'district', 'active', 'confirmed', 'deceased', 'recovered']])
```

**Breakdown**

First, get nested state dictionary from initial json load

```
state_data = d['districtsDaily']
```

Create main data frame to concatenate all sub dataframes to

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
```

Loop through each state and nested district dictionary

```
for state, districts in state_data.items():
```

Loop through each district and nested values dictionary

```
for district, values in districts.items():
```

Create district data frame, and add state and district columns

```
df_district = json_normalize(state_data, [state, district])
df_district.insert(0, 'state', state)
df_district.insert(1, 'district', district)
```

Concatenate district data frame onto main dataframe

```
df = pd.concat([df, df_district])
```

Print out only required columns in proper order

```
print(df[['date', 'state', 'district', 'active', 'confirmed', 'deceased', 'recovered']])
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. Got the logic that I was missing thanks a lot @Kurt Kline

Comment: I updated some of the naming from my first answer, and added a full breakdown. You're welcome. Also thank you, because this was a good learning experience for me. Please also mark as the answer if this indeed solves your problem.